# Prove by induction that $10^n+18^n -1$ is divisible by $ 18$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, induction, divisibility

I have tried to prove that $10^n + 18^n  -1$ is divisible by 18 like this: 
$$10^k+1 + 18^k+1  -1=\\
10^k * 10 + 18^k * 18  -1=\\
10*10^k + 18 * 18^k  -1=\\
10*10^k + 10*18^k + 8*18^k -10 +9=\\
10(10^k + 18^k -1) +8*18^k + 9$$.

But, while $10(10^k + 18^k -1)$ is divisible by $18$, i cant prove that $8*18^k + 9$ is. Can anyone help me how to prove it properly?

Comment: I highly doubt the original claim. It is an odd number ($10^n+18^n-1$). It could be possible you meant $10^n+18^{n-1}$, but then $10^n$ is not even divisible by 9.

Comment: have you substitute a few values? I don't think the statement is true too.

Comment: $10^1 + 18^1 - 1 = 27$, which to the best of my knowledge is not divisible by $18$.

Comment: Also it would be useful to write down what value's are allowed for both k and n

Comment: Well, this is how the problem was given to me by my teacher, and since we're working with mathematical induction it has become a bad habit for me to just go straight to the third step and completely skip proving that its true for n = 1. So i guess just the whole problem is incorrect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the **PMI** (Principle of Mathematical Induction), it is sufficient to prove:

1. P$(1)$ holds true
2. P$(k) \implies $ P$(k+1)$, for general $k$

Then let P$(n) = 10^n + 18^n - 1$

We try to prove P$(1)$ holds:

\begin{align}
\mathrm P(n) &= 10^n + 18^n - 1 \\
\mathrm P(1) &= 10^1 + 18^1 - 1 \\
&=10+18-1\\
&=27
\end{align}

$18 \not| \space \space \space 27$ and therefore we are finished: $10^n + 18^n - 1$ is not divisible by $18$.

Comment: It is not really P(1), but otherwise there exist some n for which P(n) is true

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, $$10^n + 18^n - 1 \equiv 10^n - 1 \pmod {18},$$ and since $18 = 2(9)$, we have $$10^n - 1 = (10-1)(10^{n-1} + 10^{n-2} + \cdots + 1) = 9(10k+1),$$ where $k = 10^{n-2} + \cdots + 1$ if $n > 1$ and $k = 0$ if $n = 1$.  Therefore $10^n + 18^n - 1 \equiv 9 \pmod {18}$ for all positive integers $n$.